# How to add or remove multiple item in Textbox using dropdwon?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to develop a tool for add or remove skill. I have Text box control when ever user click on Text box then dropdown will be open and selected item from the dropdown will be added in textbox and when click on cross then item will be remove from the textbox.

Please go though the attached file for more information.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZJ4l.png)

Comment: Use `select2` or `bootstrap tags`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>ADD SKILLS</h1>
    <textarea cols="30" rows="10" onclick="func(event)">
    </textarea>
    <select id="skill" style="display: none;">
        <option>MS OFFICE</option>
        <option>Data Entry</option>
        <option>Presentation</option>
        <option>ABELDent</option>
    </select>
    <script>
        skill = [];

        function func(event) {
            var x = event.clientX;
            var y = event.clientY;
            console.log(x, y);
            s = document.getElementById('skill');
            s.style.left = x;
            s.style.top = y;
            s.style.position = "fixed";
            s.style.zIndex = "1";
            s.style.display = "block";
            s.onchange=click;

            function click(event) {
                console.log(event.target.value);
                skill.push(event.target.value);
                document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value = skill;
                s.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Run the code in your browser and click on textbox to select.